# Can we replace "whatever" with "no matter"?

Tags: sentence-construction

The original sentence:

> Whatever it is, is what he is trying to find.

Can we replace **whatever** with **no matter** like this sentence below?

> No matter what it is, is what he is trying to find.

By the way, I made this sentence up and I also expect you to correct my sentence if there's any mistake or to suggest another natural sentence. Thanks.

Comment: You can **expect** me to do whatever you like, but you'll end up disappointed. There are several errors both of your sentences.

Comment: I don't have time for a comprehensive answer at the moment, but to be brief, **no**. The two terms are not interchangeable.

Comment: No, but more importantly, how did you make a connection between whatever and no matter?

Comment: @randomhead it's no problem. I'm OK with that. Could you explain about the errors please? I want to know. I'm always open to be corrected.

Comment: @user3169 because of my native language. They have the same translation. I mean, slightly.

Comment: @randomhead , please don't be so harsh.  Yes, in this sentence the words are not interchangeable, but in many sentences, the two terms are very similar (though still subtly different) in final meaning.  "Whatever he's trying to find" / "No matter what he's trying to find" for instance.  It's a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Richard Winters pointed out, it's a matter of context whether it works or not.

In your example, the "is, is" is a bit unusual. While your substitution doesn't work in your example, a small change makes it ok.

> Whatever it is, **it** is what he *was* trying to find.

> No matter what it is, **it** is what he *was* trying to find.

I changed the tense, because at the time some item is specified, the "finding" action would be in the past.